# Why does this navigation menu using jQuery not work?

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, navbar, nav

I am following a tutorial for a blog page and when I click the hamburger the navigation menu does not appear in screen size smaller than 750px. Here is my html code:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav-menu flex-row">
        <div class="nav-brand">
            <a href="#" class="text-grey">Blooger</a>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-collapse">
            <div class="toggle-icons">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav-items">
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">Catagory</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">Archive</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">Pages</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="social text-grey">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my jquery code that I am trying to use to toggle my navigation menu:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $nav = $('.nav');
    $toggleCollapse = $('.toggle-collapse');

    /** click event on toggle menu */
    $toggleCollapse.click(function () {
        $nav.toggleCollapse('collapse');
    })
});
```

Comment: This is not `javascript`. this is `jquery`. Do you use `jquery` CDN in your code ?

Comment: we can not check what exactly problem you facing, you need to add at least some code that we can identify the issue.

Comment: Have a read of [mcve]

Comment: @DarshabaPathum I am just following the tutorial, didn't put two in two together when we added the jquery CDN. Would this code being in a javascript file make a difference? It shouldn't because isn't jquery a form of javascript?